# how to retrive data where date is equal to current date

Tags: php, mysqli

hey i am trying to retrive data from MySQL where date = CURDATE() but its showing some kind of error

**Notice: Undefined variable: stmt in C:\wamp\www\resturent managment\todaysExpenses.php on line 48**

here is my code

```
<div class="container" align="center">

<table cellpadding="5px" cellspacing="5px" width="75%">
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Item name</th>
        <th>Item Cost</th>
        <th>Item Dated</th>
        <th>Incharge</th>

    </tr>
    <?php
    //get all moderators except deleted

    if($stmt->prepare("select id, itemName, itemCost, itemDated, itemIncharge from expenses where itemDated = CURDATE()"))
    {

        $stmt->bind_result($id, $name, $cost, $date, $incharge);
        $stmt->execute();
        if($stmt->fetch())
        {
            do
            {
            ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $id ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $name ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $cost ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $date?></td>
                <td><?php echo $incharge?></td>

            </tr>
            <?php
            }while($stmt->fetch());
        }
        else
        {
            //Todo
        }
    }
    ?>
  </table>

</div>
```

plz help me to fix this error... thanks alot

Comment: Which is line 48? Are you using a `do .. while()` instead of `while()` for a particular reason?

Comment: The error is clear enough: you haven't defined the `$stmt` variable. You're also not calling `prepare` on the right object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id, itemName, itemCost, itemDated, itemIncharge from expenses where itemDated = CURDATE()"))
```

Well, if $stmt is the variable which should manage prepared statement, only $mysqli (or the variable you used to connect to your MySQL server) have **prepare** method.

I don't see more errors.

Read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) if you need help.

Ah, [MySQLi in general](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php).

Comment: can you post the new code? because i think another problem is the missed ";" at the end of echo

Comment: its showing still the same error using ur code means that the code which u corrected

Comment: if you fixed the code as i said, you should get another error like "Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in /code/RcKjLK on line 16" Have you initialized $mysqli variable? as php wiki said something like:  `$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "world");


    if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select id, itemName, itemCost, itemDated, itemIncharge from expenses where itemDated = CURDATE()"))`

Answer (score 0):

stmt is not defined in the code that you have posted.  That must be assigned an object before you can make method calls on it.